# ¿Cómo crear jasperreport con columnas variables?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

quiero crear un documento xls con jasperreport el cual es una hoja de cálculo en el cual hay una serie de columnas (nombres de exémes) y filas (nombres de alumnos) y en las intersecciones deberá aparecer la calificación que cada alumno tiene en cada examen.

Siempre que he generado un jasperreport he hecho un SQL en el documento y así he rellenado el pdf o xls en cuestión pero en este caso el número de columnas es variable por lo que CREO que tengo que pasar como parámetro un ArrayList de ArrayList y aquí viene mi duda, ¿cómo itero luego sobre el parámetro desde jasperreport?

El ArrayList de ArrayList de String lo generaría a partir de esta SQL

```
SELECT 
  (select nombre from examen e where e.id_examen = eu.id_examen) examen ,
  (select nombre from usuario u where u.id_usuario = eu.id_usuario) usuario,
  calificacion
FROM examen_usuario  eu
where id_examen in (select id_examen from examen where ID_GRUPO = 'xxx')
order by id_examen, id_usuario;
```

La cual me genera algo como lo siguiente:

```
UD01    nombre1 0
UD01    nombre2 07,12
UD01    nombre3 05,00
UD01    nombre4 02,50
UD01    nombre5 05,35
UD01    nombre6 03,21
UD01    nombre7 05,32
UD01    nombre8 08,50
UD01    nombre9 05,62
UD02    nombre1 0
UD02    nombre2 07,72
UD02    nombre3 08,30
UD02    nombre4 04,11
UD02    nombre5 08,17
UD02    nombre6 08,46
UD02    nombre7 06,67
UD02    nombre8 08,89
UD02    nombre9 06,54
```

De modo que genero un 1er ArrayList que contiene las 9 primeras filas, un 2ndo ArrayList que contiene las 9 siguientes filas y en otro ArrayList, el que paso como parámetro al jasper, añado los 2 ArrayList

Cualquier orientación es bien recibida.

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos

edito: Añado imagen de como debería quedar:

[image: ejemplo]

Comment: Lograste hacerlo??

Comment: No, llevo 3 días atascado

Comment: Has visto Dataset and Query ??

Comment: Sería bueno que pusieras un ejemplo gráfico de como quedaría el producto final en Excel, porque creo que todo esta en función de comprender cuáles son las estructuras de datos más adecuadas a inyectar al reporte y que obviamente depende del diseño del mismo.

Comment: @RaulCacacho He estado probado con Dataset (y Listas y Tablas) sin éxito, si puedes orientarmte te agradecería

Comment: @SergioOrdóñezLópez He añadido una imagen de como quedaría el producto final en excel.

Comment: @PabloRuizSoria si claro solo ya tienes configurado la conexión a la base datos en el jasper

Comment: Hola amigo quisiera saber si pudiste resolver tu problema, yo requiero hacer algo similar, me imagino que la solución sería pasar un bean desde el aplicativo con las columnas requeridas. Pero quisiera saber cómo lo has hecho.

Comment: no pude hacerlo, siento no poder ayudarte